# Вывести записи из таблицы только за сегодня/вчера/неделю/месяц

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица MySQL. 
Каким образом можно вывести записи (присутствует поле `timestamp`) только за сегодняшний день, только за вчера, только за неделю, только за месяц?
Не за последние 24/48/168 часов, а именно за день.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),NOW()) = 0
```

0 - количество разницы между днями/месяцами (DAY/MONTH).

Могут быть, наверное, проблемы с часовым поясом, поэтому в MySQL нужно будет [установить правильный часовой пояс](http://www.opennet.ru/tips/info/1810.shtml), соответствующий данным из таблицы.

Comment: То ли лыжи не едут, то ли я что-то не так делаю(
Нуль строк выводит. Проблем с часовым поясом нету, на MySQL сервере выставлен правильный

Comment: Покажите ваш запрос. В каком поле содержится время?

Comment: Поле с названием datetime имеет тип timestamp

    SELECT * FROM `bug_table` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(`datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),NOW()) = 0 ORDER BY `datetime` DESC

Comment: Так у вас тип timestamp, так бы сразу и сказали, тогда все проще и функция FROM_UNIXTIME не нужна.

    SELECT * FROM bug_table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,datetime,NOW()) = 0 ORDER BY datetime DESC

Comment: Привык, что все UNIX юзают)

Comment: Я вас люблю, я вам раньше не говорил?))

Хорошо, смотрите, а если делать выборку вот так

WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,datetime,NOW()) = 7

То почему-то выводит записи за дату, которая была 7 дней назад (то есть записи только за один день), а мне нужно получить все записи за промежуток между той датой и сегодняшним днём

Comment: Операторы < и > никто не отменял.

    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,datetime,NOW()) <= 7

Comment: К сожалению, проблема осталась. Так же выводятся записи не за календарный день, а за "24 часа", которые отсчитываются от текущего времени(