# Вывод записей только за Сегодня/Вчера/7 дней/месяц

Tags: запрос, mysql

В продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136212/mysql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86).

Так там ничего и не вышло, как выводило не за календарный день, а за 24 часа - так и выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За текущий день:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE year(time) = year(current_timestamp)
  AND
  month(time) = month(current_timestamp)
  AND
  day(time) = day(current_timestamp);
```

За вчерашний день:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE   year(t) = year(current_timestamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND
  month(t) = month(current_timestamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND
  day(t) = day(current_timestamp - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

За текущую неделю:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE year(time) = year(current_timestamp)
  AND
  week(time) = week(current_timestamp);
```

За текущий месяц:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE year(time) = year(current_timestamp)
  AND
  month(time) = month(current_timestamp);
```